# Emoji characters changing to unknown characters

Tags: objective-c, xcode, encoding, emoji, emoticons

I am working on someone's strange code and it is changing emoji characters to strange values.

This is what I wrote:

[image: What I wrote]

It changed into:

[image]

Can someone let me know what could be happening?

Comment: You might try sharing the code that you are using.  I can think of a dozen ways to do that on purpose, but presumably, you're not doing so.

Comment: Emoji is UTF8 character, may your string is not UTF8 format.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit->Emoji and Symbols in Xcode.Type the name of symbol you want to use(in your case heart).Copy it.Then paste it the way you want. Eg:_mylabel.text=@"♥︎";

Comment: Thank you but not looking for this :)